# Show from which dictionary each line is?

Tags: python, dictionary

There are these two dictionaries with the shapefile schemas from the Fiona library that eventually have their differences printed and I need to also provide which line belongs to which dictionary :

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from pprint import pprint

>>> d1 = {'properties': OrderedDict([('KAEK', 'str:12'),
...               ('PROP_TYPE', 'str:4'),
...               ('ORI_TYPE', 'int:1'),
...               ('ORI_CODE', 'str:100'),
...               ('DEC_ID', 'str:254'),
...               ('ADDRESS', 'str:254'),
...               ('NUM', 'str:9'),
...               ('LEN', 'float:19.11'),
...               ('AREA', 'float:19.11')]),
...  'geometry': 'Polygon'}

>>> d1 = d1['properties']

>>> d2 = {'properties': OrderedDict([('OBJECTID_1', 'int:9'),
...               ('OBJECTID', 'int:9'),
...               ('FID_PERIVL', 'int:9'),
...               ('DESC_', 'str:254'),
...               ('PROP_TYPE', 'str:4'),
...               ('Shape_Leng', 'float:19.11'),
...               ('Shape_Le_1', 'float:19.11'),
...               ('Shape_Area', 'float:19.11'),
...               ('PARCEL_COD', 'str:254'),
...               ('KAEK', 'str:50'),
...               ('NUM', 'int:4'),
...               ('DEC_ID', 'int:4'),
...               ('ADDRESS', 'int:4'),
...               ('ORI_CODE', 'int:4'),
...               ('ORI_TYPE', 'int:4')]),
...  'geometry': 'Polygon'}

>>> d2 = d2['properties']
```

And I want the results to show from which dictionary originate in this final part where are listed the symmetric differences:See comments to see what I plan to do.

```
pprint(set.symmetric_difference(set(d1.items()), set(d2.items())))
{('ADDRESS', 'int:4'),#somehow inform that this belongs to d2 and so on...
 ('ADDRESS', 'str:254'),#d1
 ('AREA', 'float:19.11'),#d1
 ('DEC_ID', 'int:4'),#d2
 ('DEC_ID', 'str:254'),
 ('DESC_', 'str:254'),
 ('FID_PERIVL', 'int:9'),
 ('KAEK', 'str:12'),
 ('KAEK', 'str:50'),
 ('LEN', 'float:19.11'),
 ('NUM', 'int:4'),
 ('NUM', 'str:9'),
 ('OBJECTID', 'int:9'),
 ('OBJECTID_1', 'int:9'),
 ('ORI_CODE', 'int:4'),
 ('ORI_CODE', 'str:100'),
 ('ORI_TYPE', 'int:1'),
 ('ORI_TYPE', 'int:4'),
 ('PARCEL_COD', 'str:254'),
 ('Shape_Area', 'float:19.11'),
 ('Shape_Le_1', 'float:19.11'),
 ('Shape_Leng', 'float:19.11')}
```

Simply,classify them by name of dictionary. How can I get that happen?

Tried this:

`pprint(set(('d1', el) if el in d1.items() else ('d2', el) for el in d2.items()))` But doesn't return it correctly:

```
{('d1', ('PROP_TYPE', 'str:4')),
 ('d2', ('ADDRESS', 'int:4')),
 ('d2', ('DEC_ID', 'int:4')),
 ('d2', ('DESC_', 'str:254')),
 ('d2', ('FID_PERIVL', 'int:9')),
 ('d2', ('KAEK', 'str:50')),
 ('d2', ('NUM', 'int:4')),
 ('d2', ('OBJECTID', 'int:9')),
 ('d2', ('OBJECTID_1', 'int:9')),
 ('d2', ('ORI_CODE', 'int:4')),
 ('d2', ('ORI_TYPE', 'int:4')),
 ('d2', ('PARCEL_COD', 'str:254')),
 ('d2', ('Shape_Area', 'float:19.11')),
 ('d2', ('Shape_Le_1', 'float:19.11')),
 ('d2', ('Shape_Leng', 'float:19.11'))}
```

The correct way is to show it like the last one before that but also have the d1 and d2 information. In this order:

```
 pprint(set.symmetric_difference(set(d1.items()), set(d2.items())))
    {('ADDRESS', 'int:4'),#somehow inform that this belongs to d2 and so on...
     ('ADDRESS', 'str:254'),#d1
     ('AREA', 'float:19.11'),#d1
     ('DEC_ID', 'int:4'),#d2
     ('DEC_ID', 'str:254'),
     ('DESC_', 'str:254'),
     ('FID_PERIVL', 'int:9'),
     ('KAEK', 'str:12'),
     ('KAEK', 'str:50'),
     ('LEN', 'float:19.11'),
     ('NUM', 'int:4'),
     ('NUM', 'str:9'),
     ('OBJECTID', 'int:9'),
     ('OBJECTID_1', 'int:9'),
     ('ORI_CODE', 'int:4'),
     ('ORI_CODE', 'str:100'),
     ('ORI_TYPE', 'int:1'),
     ('ORI_TYPE', 'int:4'),
     ('PARCEL_COD', 'str:254'),
     ('Shape_Area', 'float:19.11'),
     ('Shape_Le_1', 'float:19.11'),
     ('Shape_Leng', 'float:19.11')}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
d1_items = set(d1.items())
d2_items = set(d2.items())
result = sorted([(k, 'd1', v) for k, v in d1_items if (k, v) not in d2_items] +
                [(k, 'd2', v) for k, v in d2_items if (k, v) not in d1_items])
result = [(k, v, d) for k, d, v in result]
pprint(result)
```

Output:

```
[('ADDRESS', 'str:254', 'd1'),
 ('ADDRESS', 'int:4', 'd2'),
 ('AREA', 'float:19.11', 'd1'),
 ('DEC_ID', 'str:254', 'd1'),
 ('DEC_ID', 'int:4', 'd2'),
 ('DESC_', 'str:254', 'd2'),
 ('FID_PERIVL', 'int:9', 'd2'),
 ('KAEK', 'str:12', 'd1'),
 ('KAEK', 'str:50', 'd2'),
 ('LEN', 'float:19.11', 'd1'),
 ('NUM', 'str:9', 'd1'),
 ('NUM', 'int:4', 'd2'),
 ('OBJECTID', 'int:9', 'd2'),
 ('OBJECTID_1', 'int:9', 'd2'),
 ('ORI_CODE', 'str:100', 'd1'),
 ('ORI_CODE', 'int:4', 'd2'),
 ('ORI_TYPE', 'int:1', 'd1'),
 ('ORI_TYPE', 'int:4', 'd2'),
 ('PARCEL_COD', 'str:254', 'd2'),
 ('Shape_Area', 'float:19.11', 'd2'),
 ('Shape_Le_1', 'float:19.11', 'd2'),
 ('Shape_Leng', 'float:19.11', 'd2')]
```

Comment: This is great but can you make it appear in the order of the last result I posted ?Like `d1`with the correspond different `d2` and then all the extra `d2` alone in the end.

Comment: You mean like `{(('ADDRESS', 'str:254'), 'd1'), ...`, etc? The order of the elements is arbitrary in sets, but a list can be used if you want to have elements from `d1` first and elements from `d2` later.

Comment: No that's not what I meant. That would be ridiculous. I mean for columns that exist in both dictionaries to appear together for readability:address of `d1` then address `d2` not all the `d1` and then all the `d2`.Maybe requires to be turned to dataframes?

Comment: Now it only lacks the `d1` and `d2` notations in that order and you are set. Can you do it?

Comment: @user122244 I guess, you mean like this? (actually you can skip the line before `pprint` if you don't mind having `d1`/`d2` in the middle...